# Detecting all currently signaled semaphores

Tags: c, windows, winapi, semaphore

Is there a way to find out all currently signaled semaphores in windows?

One approach is to call WaitForMultipleObjects(bWaitAll=FALSE, dwMilliseconds=0)
repeatedly, each time removing one (signaled) HANDLE, until we get a WAIT_TIMEOUT,
but this is cumbersome and slow.

Is there a better way?

Comment: It is pretty fundamental that doing this is *never* correct.  All you know that it *was* signaled, you know nothing about the current state.  The winapi doesn't give you an easy way to do the wrong thing.

Comment: I don't need the exact *current* state, but do need to quickly handle a batch of (released) resources as soon as can.  
Your logic can be slightly stretched to claim that WaitForMultipleObjects(bWaitAll=TRUE) on semaphores is also never correct.

Answer (score 0):

`WaitForSingleObject()`? I don't think any of the standard functions will give a bitmask/array of signalled objects.

Comment: WaitForSingleObject() is even worse: we always have to call it n times

Comment: But how does that compare to the repeated `WaitForMultipleObjects()` reshuffling the array each time? I understand it will be one call for each rather than one for each signalled, but the overhead of the reshuffling may offset that depending on how many are signalled.

Comment: No reshuffling is needed: a simple handles[r] = handles[--n] will do, which is orders of magnitude faster than making a system call.